# sqlite db which doesn't hold the value and shows login page everytime android

Tags: android, sqlite

i am using below sqlite db code to store the value but on close of app the values are  cleared in the db and shows login page everytime can anyone please tell what is fault in this code.

```
package com.example.library;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pat_manager";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "user_reg";

 // Login Table Columns names

    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER = "phone_number";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "user_id";
    private static final String KEY_USER_GROUP = "user_group";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

 // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"               
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_USER_GROUP + " TEXT"
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
       }

 // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String username, String name, String email, String user_id, String 
            phone_number,String user_group) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, username); // LastName
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Email
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // UserName       
        values.put(KEY_UID, user_id); // Created At
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER, phone_number); // State
        values.put(KEY_USER_GROUP, user_group); // City

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        System.out.println("entered into addUser function");
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String,String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        System.out.println("select query:"+selectQuery);
        System.out.println("entering into hashmap");

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        System.out.println("cursor count is");
        System.out.println(cursor.getCount());
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            System.out.println("enter into if of hashmap");
            user.put("user_id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_UID)));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
            user.put("username", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERNAME)));
            user.put("user_group", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_GROUP)));
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));           
             }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }


    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }// end



}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

no way to tell from the code you provided...but i'll take a guess that you are not in a transaction...and therefore are not committing the transaction to the DB.

```
sqlDB.open(); // sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase()
sqlDB.beginTransaction();

int numRowsAffected = sqlDB.<your insert function>();

if (numRowsAffected > 0) {
   sqlDB.setTransactionSucessful(); 
}
sqlDB.endTransaction();
sqlDB.close();  // sqlHelper.close()
```

good luck.

Comment: in the answer (above) you see `<your insert function>`. that's your `insert` statement. put my code around it.

Comment: it wouldn't hurt to run thru the tutorial at: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html